# Only one part of url needs to be 301 redirected

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, redirect, partial

I need to redirect on a bunch or URL's in my website.

I have 
http://www.myurl.lt/lt/imone/landstar-lt-lt/?cms_action=manage and I need to redirect it to http://www.myurl.lt/lt/imone/landstar-lt-lt/

I have about 700 of them, so is it possible to do a redirect with one redirect command?

Comment: What do these urls have in common?

Comment: Your question is not very clear. Do you want an apache `mod_rewrite` rule for that? And do you want to remove all get params or only the `cms_action`? What you have tried so far?

Comment: I want to use mod_rewrite. And i want to remove only cms_action. At the moment I havent tried a thing to do so far, it's a new website. These two URL'as have same content and its being indexed on both URL's. Like i wrote before, I want to get rid of cms_action. URL can differ before /?cms_action

Comment: Are `/it/` and `/it/imone/` real directories?

Comment: Anubhava, yes they are

Answer (score 0):

This rules should remove the `cms_action` param, but preserve all other params

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.+?&|)cms_action=[^&]*(?:&(.*)|)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}?%1%2 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Place this rule in `/it/imone/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /it/imone/

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /([^?]*)\?cms_action=manage [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1/? [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !(^|&)cms_action=manage(&|$) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}?cms_action=manage [L,QSA]
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a Rewrite, which doesn't make any sense to me in this situation, why don't you just redirect the user directly from the manage action? This will definitely add to clarity. If you were using PHP for example:

```
// Inside manage action
header('Location: http://www.myurl.lt/lt/imone/landstar-lt-lt/');
```

Comment: Well its the problem of CMS, so it creates both URL's. It is called impresspages if you've heard about it. It has a lot of problems, programmer run off so now I need to work with what I have, so redirect is the only solution for now.

Comment: Instead of Rewrites why dont you redirect the way i showed you? by sending a header?